# What happens to the earth after volcanism/tectonics slows?

Tags: volcanology, tectonics

If we move far enough into the future that the core begins to solidify to the point that volcanism and tectonics are non-existent, what does the surface of the planet begin to look like?  Does the planet eventually become fully covered in water due to erosion?

Comment: you can look at venus and mercury, as the planet cools it shrinks which actually causes something similar to plate tectonics at least for a while.

Comment: Related: [Is the Earth's hot inner core necessary for life?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/240/725) and [As the earth's core cools, will the size be affected?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/8588/725) and [At what point does plate tectonics stop?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2843/725) and [How long until Earth's core solidifies?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2523/725)